# InnoSetup - how can you have inline comments in the setup source?

Tags: comments, inline, inno-setup

Does anyone know if there is a way to add inline comments to InnoSetup source files?

I've done some experiments:

```
;   a comment                                       (allowed)

[Setup]
AppName=MyApp                       // a comment    (allowed)
AppVersion=1.2.3.4                  ; a comment     (allowed)
DefaultDirName="{pf}\My App"        seems you can have anything at all here (allowed)

[Dirs]
Name: "{userdocs}\My App"
Name: {userdocs}\MyApp              // a comment    (allowed)
Name: "{userdocs}\My App"           // a comment    (not allowed)
Name: {userdocs}\MyApp ;            // a comment    (not allowed)
Name: "{userdocs}\My App" ;         // a comment    (not allowed)
```

and (I think) I've found that a comment is allowed anywhere where the compiler isn't expecting any more operands, but I would prefer to use a more rigid syntax, if one exists.

Comment: In the *script* section (anything but `[Code]`), the semicolon is used to inline a comment. In the name value sections it is not possible to inline a comment because the value portion is not enclosed anyhow and so what's behind the equal sign is the value, no matter what it is. And semicolon separated sections cannot inline it too just because it's their separator. You have actually only one comment in your example script, the first one.

Comment: Thanks @TLama, yep, that's what I figured.  In fact, where I said `a comment is allowed anywhere where the compiler isn't expecting any more operands`, what I should have said was "the compiler doesn't check for unexpected operands on a line".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### How to comment in the script part of the source ?

In the script part of the source (which includes all the sections except the [`[Code]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcreating) one), a semicolon at the beginning of a line separates a comment. It's described in the [`Script Format Overview`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptformatoverview.htm) topic as (emphasized by me):

> You can put "comments" in the script (which are ignored by the
>   compiler) **by placing a semicolon at the beginning of a line**. For
>   example:
>
> `; This is a comment. I could put reminders to myself here...`

So, that's about the script comment separator (for sections except [`[Code]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcreating) one). Now, let's think about why we can't inline comments to any of those sections.

### Why comments cannot be inlined in name value sections ?

In the name value sections like e.g. [`[Setup]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupsection.htm), [`[Messages]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection) or similar, you cannot inline comments for their entries because the value portion is everything what follows the equal sign, no matter what it is. So, there is no comment in the following example section. Instead, the directives got pretty long and quite exotic values:

```
[Setup]
AppName=MyApp                       // a comment    (allowed)
AppVersion=1.2.3.4                  ; a comment     (allowed)
DefaultDirName="{pf}\My App"        seems you can have anything at all here (allowed)
```

Correct way to comment them would be to use separate lines starting with semicolons:

```
[Setup]
; comment for AppName
AppName=MyApp
; comment for AppVersion
AppVersion=1.2.3.4
; comment for DefaultDirName
DefaultDirName={pf}\My App
```

### Why comments cannot be inlined in semicolon separated sections ?

For sections with semicolon separated parameters should not be possible to inline semicolon separated comment, just because of their separator. If that is possible in some condition, I would consider that as a (minor) bug caused by the compiler parser's laziness.